# How to concatenate a patchValue number with a string in angular forms?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

This is my TS

```typescript
      ngOnInit() {
        this.editProfileForm = new FormGroup({
          firstNumber: new FormControl(null, {
            validators: [Validators.required],
          })
        }
      }

      fetchNumber() {
        this.nameService.fetchName().subscribe(
          () => {
            this.editProfileForm.patchValue({
              firstNumber: this.profileData.firstnumber,
            });
          },
        );
      }
```

my HTML

```html
            <ion-col>
              <ion-input
                *ngIf="nameData"
                type="number"
                inputmode="numeric"
                formControlName="firstNumber"
                placeholder="First number" >
                <ion-button clear icon-only fill="clear">
                  <ion-icon [src]="icons.info"></ion-icon>
                </ion-button>
              </ion-input>
            </ion-col>
```

What I want to achieve is when I have my input in HTML that gets filled with the value of `firstNumber` to add also the string "%". I've tried with "+"

```typescript
    firstNumber: this.profileData.firstNumber + "%";
```

, putting "%" in a variable and still doesn't work. If you guys have any if this can be done I would really appreciate it.

Comment: * did you verify that the type of `profileData.firstname` is a string? *did you try adding parentheses?  `firstName:(this.profileData.firstname + "%")` *did you try using a template string? ``like`"${this.profileData.firstname}%"`.``

Comment: @PMO1948 you are right... I stupidly didn't realise that in my code I had a number coming in, but still doesn't work any option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Add the % in the input field using pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-133zfr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

first create the formcontrolname and bind the value in the input text

<input type="text" formControlName="amount" [value]="myform.get('controlname')|pipe">

i attached the stackbliz,kindly refer it

Comment: unfortunately if you write quickly the symbol stays in the middle of the value (if you print the form you can see)